# Difference Between OpenCV's Haar Cascade Classifiers

Tags: opencv, opencv3.0, face-detection, opencv3.1

OpenCV provides several Haar Cascade classidiers for face detection:

```
- haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml 
- haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml
- haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml
- haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml
```

I wonder what is the difference between these classifiers.

I have noticed that, in application, the "default" version returns more false positives than the "alt" and "alt2" versions; and the "alt_tree" version is the most rigorous one. However, I am looking for their fundamental differences. For example, if anyone knows what database is used for their training.

Thanks

Comment: Just open the XML files. You can see an explanation about each one of them.

Comment: This question is similar and useful. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440283/how-to-choose-the-cascade-file-for-face-detection/20999727