# What is the difference between Stump-based and Tree-based frontal face detector?

Tags: opencv, face-recognition, haar-classifier, cascade-classifier

I have seen few options of haar-cascades for frontal face recognition such as:
`"haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml"
"haarcascade_frontalface_alt_tree.xml"
"haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml"
"haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml"`

Basically they all do the same task. What are the major differences between them?

Comment: different training parameters and/or training data

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4440283/how-to-choose-the-cascade-file-for-face-detection